# How to bind XML fragments in ButterKnife?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, butterknife

**fragment in xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/parent_fragment"
    android:name="com.app.example.ParentFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**binding in activity**

```
@BindView(R.id.parent_fragment)
ParentFragment parentFragment;
```

**gradle build error message**

> @BindView fields must extend from View or be an interface

Is there something like `@BindFragment` for binding XML fragments using `@+id`?

I am sorry if this is something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there is no such annotation in that library.

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Since there will not be a lot of fragments in your activity, using a library might not be necessary. Just use the classical approach using `FragmentManager`

```
parentFragment = (ParentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.parent_fragment);
```

Comment: thanks. But, I need it. I added [#1133](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1133) at github